# Remove notification after cliking on Android

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, notifications

I'm currently using a plugin for Unity that allows me to push "local" notifications. It works fine except for one thing : notification don't disappear after clicking it.

Here is the code :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    Log.d("Unity", "Alarm Recieved!");      
    NotificationManager mNM = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);        
    Bundle bb = intent.getExtras();
    Class<?> cc = null;

    try 
    {
      cc = context.getClassLoader().loadClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity");
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) 
    {
      e1.printStackTrace();
      return;
    }

    final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = null;

    try 
    {
      applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(),PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    } 
    catch (NameNotFoundException e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return;
    }

    final int appIconResId = applicationInfo.icon;
    Notification notification = new Notification(appIconResId, (String)bb.get("name"), System.currentTimeMillis());

    //notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL

    int id = (int)(Math.random()*10000.0f)+1;
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, new Intent(context, cc), 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, (String)bb.get("title"), (String)bb.get("label"), contentIntent);
    Log.i("Unity", "notify("+id+") with "+(String)bb.get("title")+", "+(String)bb.get("label"));                
    mNM.notify(id, notification);
}
```

Even if i'm not a java developper, i understand most of the parts of this code. I already tried some tricks like :

```
notification.setAutoCancel(true);

notification.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

But as i'm expecting, that's not working...

So, does anyone can explain to me how to achieve this ?
Thanks mates !

Comment: Have you tried: new Notification.Builder().setAutoCancel(true).build()?

Comment: Not yet. Should I copy/paste it right on the bottom of the method ?

Comment: Don't use "new Notification()" use the builder to create the notification instead. It's called a builder pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help you:

```
 NotificationManager  mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Destination.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,intent , 0);
    Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    long[] vibration = {0, 200, 50, 200};
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                    .setContentTitle("MyCar Notification")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(msg))
                    .setSound(uri)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS)
                    .setVibrate(vibration)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentText(msg);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    int NOTIFICATION_ID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL

Answer (score 0):

After adding the flag Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL (or calling .setAutoCancel(true)) and rebuilding your Unity project, please go to Phone Settings -> Apps, find your App and click it, then click the "FORCE STOP" button. Now launch you app again and it should work.